# Centos 6 lamp server security

Tags: wordpress, security, centos, phpbb, selinux

In the past week I've installed a centos6 lamp server and set up wordpress for my website and phpbb for my forum. As far as security goes, are there any measures you guys recommend? From what I've been reading for wordpress, there are plugins for security and methods like changing and deleting admin accounts. For phpbb I don't really know what to do. My main focus is on my server though. This was the first server I have ever set up so I know it's not secure. I read that mod_security and mod_evasive are good counter measures. For the mean time i have disabled selinux because it prevents me from viewing my forum page(any ideas on what to do?), but I know it's good to configure, but just so confusing. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably off-topic for `stackoverflow`, you might look at `serverfault`. However, some quick hints:

1. Disable access to all unnecessary ports, probably by configuring `iptables`. You shouldn't need to open more than 22,80, and 443.
2. If you do run `ssh`, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and disable root login. I recommend DenyHosts as well.
3. Turn SELinux back on. You just need to use setsebool to enable the right things. This might be all you need

   ```
   $ sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
   ```
4. This will let you look at related booleans.

   ```
   $ getsebool -a | egrep '(http|php)'
   ```